# How to let the frame go top level in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter, frame

[image]

How to let the frame go top in tkinter? I tried to use both grid and place, both useless.
Also, I want to display a small float window while I click any button to let me select confirm or cancel. Could you let me know hwo to create the float windows in tkinter

```
class MYGUI():
    def __init__(self, root) -> None:
        self.root = root
        self.btn_list_names = list(range(9,-1,-1))+['.','←']
        self.btn_list_btns = []
        self.btn_list_cmd={
            9:self.btn_9,
            8:self.btn_8,
            7:self.btn_7,
            6:self.btn_6,
            5:self.btn_5,
            4:self.btn_4,
            3:self.btn_3,
            2:self.btn_2,
            1:self.btn_1,
            0:self.btn_0,
            '.':self.btn_dot,
            '←':self.btn_delete,
            
        }

        self.numpad_frame = Frame(self.root,width=200,height=250,bg='blue')

    
        self.numpad_create()

    def btn_9(self):
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,'9')
    def btn_8(self):
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,'8')
    def btn_7(self):
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,'7')
    def btn_6(self):
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,'6')
    def btn_5(self):
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,'5')
    def btn_4(self):
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,'4')
    def btn_3(self):
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,'3')
    def btn_2(self):
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,'2')
    def btn_1(self):
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,'1')
    def btn_0(self):
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,'0')
    def btn_dot(self):
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,'.')
    def btn_delete(self):
        value = self.test_entry.focus_get().get()
        self.test_entry.focus_get().delete(0,END)
        self.test_entry.focus_get().insert(END,value[:-1])

    def setup(self):
        self.root.geometry('1068x681+10+10')
        self.test_entry = Entry(self.root)
        self.test_entry.place(x=0,y=0,width=100,height=20)
        self.test_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event:self.numpad_frame.place(x=105,y=25))

        self.test_entry1 = Entry(self.root)
        self.test_entry1.place(x=0,y=25,width=100,height=20)
        self.test_entry1.bind("<FocusIn>",lambda event:self.numpad_frame.place(x=105,y=45))

        self.test_entry2 = Entry(self.root)
        self.test_entry2.place(x=105,y=0,width=100,height=20)
        self.test_entry2.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event:self.numpad_frame.place(x=205,y=25))

        self.test_entry3 = Entry(self.root)
        self.test_entry3.place(x=105,y=25,width=100,height=20)
        self.test_entry3.bind("<FocusIn>",lambda event:self.numpad_frame.place(x=205,y=45))

    def numpad_create(self):
        sr,sc=0,0
        init_sc = sc
        for b in self.btn_list_names:
            cmd = self.btn_list_cmd[b]
            Button(self.numpad_frame, text=b, width=5,command=cmd).grid(row=sr,column=sc)
            sc += 1
            if sc>=init_sc+3:
                sr+=1
                sc= init_sc
```

please have a look the codes, thank you so much if could give me some suggestions

Comment: Dialogs (floating toplevel windows) are created using the tk.Toplevel command. These can be modal (like a messagebox) or non-modal where the user can still interact with the application windows while the toplevel window is present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `tkraise()` for the frame everywhere (Every Entry widget in your case) you are willing the frame to be rise above:

```
self.test_entry.bind("<FocusIn>", lambda event:self.numpad_frame.place(x=105,y=25), self.numpad_frame.tkraise())
```

---

> Could you let me know how to create the float windows in tkinter?

You can use [tkinter.messagebox](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.messagebox.html) for such purpose. Use **messagebox.askokcancel** to ask the user to select between confirm or cancel.

PS: Try to place the frame at coordinates such that it does not overlap with the Entry widgets, as is happening in your case, because it builds a pretty poor UI. And please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) when you ask a question.